# publishing asp.net mvc using azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

**Edit:**

I am deploying my ASP.NET MVC entity framework using azure, but faced with a problem. I have two projects to publish, one of them is a class library, but seems class library is not published.

Reading this post,
[Deploying web site to Azure as well as class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437874/deploying-web-site-to-azure-as-well-as-class-library), I found that it is related to the model DLL files. Should the model file be located in the Web Application project's bin folder? or the class library's bin folder? What is potentially causing the issue?

[image: test1.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to you class library from the MVC web application. So when you build `.dll` of your class library will be copied to `/bin` folder of the web application.